# How to disable "Laptop battery low" notification in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell

Is it possible to disable the below notification but keep the "Battery critically low" one intact?

[image]

Comment: This is not the problem. Albeit it says "25 minutes remaining", I can easily work for another hour. Hence this message is useless to me.

Comment: @heynnema thanks, your comment helped me. My laptop was low on battery and it never occurred to me that charging it would make this notification go away. Speaking of lateral thinking, huh! Mind posting that as an answer?